# How to find HTTP POST details

Tags: http, post

I wan't to create and send POST request (via C#) to the specific server. But I don't know how to get POST details, i.e. value from input tag. I see only Request Payload in Developer tools:
[image]

Comment: It's not a form POST. The content-type is mentioned and the payload _is_ the POST data.

Comment: I would expect '1660215' to see in POST data, so I can create POST request.